# Select from pandas dataframe using boolean series/array

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
             High    Low  Close
Date                           
2009-02-11  30.20  29.41  29.87
2009-02-12  30.28  29.32  30.24
2009-02-13  30.45  29.96  30.10
2009-02-17  29.35  28.74  28.90
2009-02-18  29.35  28.56  28.92
```

and a boolean series:

```
     bools
1    True
2    False
3    False
4    True
5    False
```

how could I select from the dataframe using the boolean array to obtain result like:

```
             High   
Date                           
2009-02-11  30.20  
2009-02-17  29.35
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For the indexing to work with two DataFrames they have to have comparable indexes. In this case it won't work because one `DataFrame` has an integer index, while the other has dates.

However, as you say you *can* filter using a `bool` *array*. You can access the array for a `Series` via `.values`. This can be then applied as a filter as follows:

```
df # pandas.DataFrame
s  # pandas.Series 

df[s.values] # df, filtered by the bool array in s
```

For example, with your data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
            [30.20,  29.41,  29.87],
            [30.28,  29.32,  30.24],
            [30.45,  29.96,  30.10],
            [29.35,  28.74,  28.90],
            [29.35,  28.56,  28.92],
        ],
        columns=['High','Low','Close'], 
        index=['2009-02-11','2009-02-12','2009-02-13','2009-02-17','2009-02-18']
        )

s = pd.Series([True, False, False, True, False], name='bools')

df[s.values]
```

Returns the following:

```
            High    Low     Close
2009-02-11  30.20   29.41   29.87
2009-02-17  29.35   28.74   28.90
```

If you just want the High column, you can filter this as normal (before, or after the `bool` filter):

```
df['High'][s.values]
# Or: df[s.values]['High']
```

To get your target output (as a `Series`):

```
 2009-02-11    30.20
 2009-02-17    29.35
 Name: High, dtype: float64
```

Comment: So, index is the problem. Thank you! That's amazing! Sorry for being late. :D

Answer (score 0):

just a small variation on the answer above.
By applying the index of the dataframe on the series, it can be utilized as df[s]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
            [30.20,  29.41,  29.87],
            [30.28,  29.32,  30.24],
            [30.45,  29.96,  30.10],
            [29.35,  28.74,  28.90],
            [29.35,  28.56,  28.92],
        ],
        columns=['High','Low','Close'], 
        index=['2009-02-11','2009-02-12','2009-02-13','2009-02-17','2009-02-18']
        )

s = pd.Series([True, False, False, True, False], index=df.index, name='bools')

# df[s.values]
df[s]
```